# Collapse section when click cell in UITableView in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a UITableView in which number of section and number of cell under those sections are coming from my service. The number of section are dynamic and contain dynamic cell under it. Depends on the data coming from service. I want to collapse section when cell is clicked. Each section should collapsed when the cell under it is clicked. How can i collapsed that? I have searched a lot for it but mostly results are showing when we tap on section it expand and collapsed. But i want to collapse section on click of cell. My code for placing data in section header is this,

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    if tableView == resMenuTableView{

        return subCategoryModel!.count
    }
    else
    {
        return AddonCategoryModel!.count
    }
}
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {

    if tableView == resMenuTableView{

        return subCategoryModel![section].subCatName

    }
    else
    {
         return AddonCategoryModel![section].name
    }
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if tableView == resMenuTableView{
        return subCategoryModel![section].items.count
    }
    else
    {
        return AddonCategoryModel![section].addonItems.count
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you click on cell you will get section from `indexPath.section`. You can update viewState to set section collapse flag and then reload table. Section whose collapse flag is set assign number of rows 0 for that section.

If at a time only one section collapses in table it will be easy for you to handle logic.

Comment: how can i update viewState? Where to reload table in viewForHeader delegate? @Aaina Jain

Comment: If you don't have view state then take one global variable i.e. `collapseSection` as mentioned in below answer. If you want any section collapsed at first time then set value to this variable. Then you need to compare `indexPath.section` with `collapseSection` in `numberOfRowsInSection` method. If section matches then return 1 else `countOfRows`. Here `countOfRows` will be from array/dictionary as you have dynamic data. By returning 1 as number of row one cell will be visible always. This visible cell could help you in expand section if it's requirement.

Comment: You can reload table using `tableView.reloadData()` in `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` method after setting value in `collapseSection`.

Comment: can u please give any example i'm not getting this. @Aaina Jain

Answer (score 0):

Take a global Int Value without initializing.

```
var selectedSection: Int!
```

When tapped on cell, assign the section index of the cell to selectedSection and reload that section. If you want to uncollapse remaining sections, just reload entire tableview instead reloading just one section.

```
selectedSection = indexPath.section
tableView.reloadSections(IndexSet(integer: selectedSection), with: .top)
```

In numberOfCellsForSection method check whether the section and selectedSection are same. If they are same you need to collapse the section that means you need to give the original rows count.

Comment: it reloads the table view but does not collapse it. @Hari

Comment: So, you have issue with collapsing animation right?

Comment: If you are reloading entire table data it is hard to achieve animation. Try reloading one section with animation. tableView.reloadSections(IndexSet(integer: selectedSection), with: .automic)

Comment: i have done with this it changes its place but does not properly close the section. @Hari

Comment: You need to maintain a previously selected section also. When user selected a cell, you need to reload selected section and previously selected section. Reload both with animation.

Comment: animate with top animation? @Hari

Comment: Try something which will give you good effect. top, bottom or automatic.

Comment: i have tried all of them but they don't properly close the section. @Hari